# spark convert a string to TimestampType

Tags: postgresql, datetime, apache-spark, jdbc

I have a dataframe that I want to insert into Postgresql in spark. In spark the DateTimestamp column is in string format.In postgreSQL it is TimeStamp without time zone.

Spark errors out when inserting into the database on the date time column. I did try to change the data type but the insert still errors out. I am unable to figure out why the cast does not work.If I paste the same insert string into PgAdmin and run, the insert statement runs fine.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar
object EtlHelper {
 // Return the current time stamp

  def getCurrentTime() : String = {    
    val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()   
    val hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")   
    return hourFormat.format(now)   
  }
 }
```

In another file

```
object CreateDimensions {

def createDimCompany(spark:SparkSession, location:String, propsLocation :String):Unit = {      
import spark.implicits._    

val dimCompanyStartTime = EtlHelper.getCurrentTime()
val dimcompanyEndTime = EtlHelper.getCurrentTime()
val prevDimCompanyId = 2
val numRdd = 27
val AuditDF = spark.createDataset(Array(("dim_company", prevDimCompanyId,numRdd,dimCompanyStartTime,dimcompanyEndTime))).toDF("audit_tbl_name","audit_tbl_id","audit_no_rows","audit_tbl_start_date","audit_tbl_end_date")//.show()

AuditDF.withColumn("audit_tbl_start_date",AuditDF.col("audit_tbl_start_date").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType))
AuditDF.withColumn("audit_tbl_end_date",AuditDF.col("audit_tbl_end_date").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType))

AuditDF.printSchema()
}  
}

root
 |-- audit_tbl_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- audit_tbl_id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- audit_no_rows: long (nullable = false)
 |-- audit_tbl_start_date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- audit_tbl_end_date: string (nullable = true)
```

This is the error I get

```
INSERT INTO etl.audit_master ("audit_tbl_name","audit_tbl_id","audit_no_rows","audit_tbl_start_date","audit_tbl_end_date") VALUES ('dim_company',27,2,'2018-05-02 12:15:54','2018-05-02 12:15:59') was aborted: ERROR: column "audit_tbl_start_date" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How do `audit_tbl_start_date` and `audit_tbl_end_date` look like? Please add code to reproduce your dataset

Comment: @Gevorg, I just edited to include more code. Hopefully you can reproduce the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is what @Ramesh mentioned i.e. that you didn't assign the changes in the AuditDF  to a new  value (val) note that both the dataframe and the value you assigned it to are immutable (i.e. auditDF was defined  val so it also can't be changed)

Another thing is that you don't need to reinvent the wheel and use the EtlHelper spark has built-in function that gives you a timestamp of current time:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val AuditDF = spark.createDataset(Array(("dim_company", prevDimCompanyId,numRdd)))
.toDF("audit_tbl_name","audit_tbl_id","audit_no_rows")
.withColumn("audit_tbl_start_date"current_timestamp())
.withColumn("audit_tbl_end_date",current_timestamp())
```

Comment: I have refactored my code to include the spark current_timestamp instead of the EtlHelper. It seems to be faster this way, vs calling the EtlHelper and casting the string to timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

`AuditDF.printSchema()` is taking the original `AuditDF` dataframe since you didn't save the transformations of `.withColumn` by assigning. **Dataframes are immutable objects which can be transformed to another dataframes but cannot change itself. So you would always need an assignment to save the transformations you've applied.**

so the correct way is to assign in order to save the changes

```
val transformedDF = AuditDF.withColumn("audit_tbl_start_date",AuditDF.col("audit_tbl_start_date").cast(DataTypes.TimestampType))
                          .withColumn("audit_tbl_end_date",AuditDF.col("audit_tbl_end_date").cast("timestamp"))

transformedDF.printSchema()
```

you shall see the changes

```
root
 |-- audit_tbl_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- audit_tbl_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- audit_no_rows: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- audit_tbl_start_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- audit_tbl_end_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

`.cast(DataTypes.TimestampType)` and `.cast("timestamp")` are both same

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is true. I should have assigned to a new val. And thanks for the .cast examples.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, because this also works, Its amazing how flexible spark is.